# Como validar si tengo comillas sin valor en un json en java

Tags: java, json

espero y se encuentren bien, estoy intentando validar una cadena json que seria por ejemplo esta:

```
[{"cve_device":2,"cve_version":0,"device_version":"","version_id":"12","actual_fw":"","fw_to_update":"","user_cve":"123456","statusAccionInsertUpdate":1}]
```

Y mi validador seria algo como este:

```
 if(jsonFromJavaArrayList.contains("\"")) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Error: ", "Favor de completar el registro."));
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaControlDevice");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(3000)");
    }
```

Pero asi como está no me funciona, he visto que se puede hacer con escapar caracteres, pero no he tenido la suerte de encontrar un ejemplo claro, mas que nada lo que quiero es validar los puros `""` ignorando por completo los demás, espero y me puedan ayudar amigos, se los agradecería bastante, quedo al pendiente, saludos y buen inicio de semana.

Comment: Solo necesitas escapar el carácter una vez más. De la siguiente manera: "\"\""